# ImageView масштабирование

Tags: java, android, imageview, масштабирование

В `ImageView` загружаю картинку `480х606`, размер `ImageView` на экране `1080х680`.
Как бы не пробовал, но не получаю желаемого результата и даже увеличивал картинку в фотошопе, а после загружал ее в `ImageView` но она загружалась как с исходными значениями.Если ее масштабировать `centerCrop`, то верх картинки обрезается, а низ остается.

Задача

> Растянуть картинку в ImageView таким образом что бы вверх картинки не
> обрезался ImageView , а начинался как оригинал, а низ пускай срежится.

Comment: Вроде как стандартными средствами так не смаштабировать. Вроде как единственный вариант - картинку в Bitmap получить и обрезать этот Bitmap программно по размерам ImageView (точнее - по её ширине и, наверное, по высоте, вычисленным в пикселях.)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так я обрезал она все равно растягивается.Может тогда ее проще отрисовать через канву?

Answer (score 1):

Создать кастомный класс отнаследованный от AppCompatImageView

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        updateMatrix();
    }

    private void updateMatrix() {
        final Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            final Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
            final float viewWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
            final float viewHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
            final float drawableWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            final float drawableHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            final float scale = drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth ?
                viewHeight / drawableHeight : viewWidth / drawableWidth;
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
    }
}
```

Использовать его там где необходимо подобное поведение.

```
<com.example.myapplication.CustomImageView
        android:id=...
        android:src=...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="680dp"
        .../>
```

Чтобы задать высоту картинки в пропорциях от ширины экрана, во Фрагмете:

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        final int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        final ImageView image = binding.image; // Либо через findViewById(...)
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageLayoutParams = image.getLayoutParams();
        final float ratio = 0.8f; // Нужное отношение высоты к ширине картинки
        imageLayoutParams.height = Math.round(screenWidth * ratio);
        
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Так я сам делал но эффект не тот.Вот картинка https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-images-cbir/1468116/4-tbRaNh3c5tVd8fDvUh8Q526/ocr нужно в ImageView шириной на всю ширину экрана и высотой в 250dp уместить эту картинку, вдруг вокруг она загружается идеально, чуть обрезается низ и все.А я как не пробовал то она тянется то слишком большая.

Comment: У меня так получается: https://i.ibb.co/sw9PfkB/2022-05-15-19-43-35.png Нужно как-то иначе?

Comment: Нужно что бы девушка была видна почти полностью как это будет если загрузить фото это в друг вокруг или beboo

Comment: У них вьюшки куда загружаются фото почти квадратные: https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/PurpleSource125/v4/5e/4e/36/5e4e364b-dd39-389f-122d-f8a16d24d92b/cb539c51-bd54-4eab-b2e2-26eea0a33afe_55_03.jpg/750x750bb.jpeg https://myfreesoft.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/drug-vokrug-password-change-step-1-357x550.jpg, по этому влезает почти полностью. Формат 1080х680(1080х250) это прямоугольники с длиной в 2-3 раза большей чем высота - при таких размерах либо у фото будет значительная область отрезаться, либо пустые области по бокам оставлять, либо непропорционально растягивать. Как по другому?

Comment: Там наверное 1080х1080. Если 1080х680 то как по ширине вычислить высоту для экранов побольше/меньше что бы фото смотрелось одинаково?

Comment: Обновил свой ответ с описанием как это сделать.